# Comparing Heroku Postgres and Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, heroku

I'm currently trying to figure out what type of database hosting I should use for a new project. Since I'm not the best at managing and configuring servers, Heroku is my go-to PaaS.

However, someone told me I should look into using Amazon RDS as database instead of Heroku Postgres to get more bang for the buck. I've tried to compare the two, but honestly, I can't figure out if it's worth it since their price models are so different and because I'm not sure how a Heroku Standard-0 instance compares to a RDS t1.micro.

I would love to hear some opinions from someone with experience of both Heroku Postgres and Amazon RDS. Generally, is it worth to use RDS when my app will be on Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you view the ease vs cost trade-off. I've found that, very roughly, it's half the cost for HA Postgres Databases in RDS vs those in Heroku.

The cost of Standard-0 is $50/month and the cost of the 64 GB storage is included. The cost of db.t1.micro is $0.026/hour is roughly $18.72/month $6.40 for storage.

So, very roughly it would be:
$25.12/month vs $50/month

If I were starting a project, for ease of setup and management I'd start in Heroku Postgres. I would make sure I had a migration plan in place for when the cost became a factor, and then move to RDS.

Cheers,
   John